# jquery knob change colors with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery knob plugin.

Source: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

I am aware of it's options, that you can edit in JS file.

### Question:

How to change **colors** ( fgColor, bgColor ) with **CSS** ?

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="1" class="dial">
```

### JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".dial").knob({
        readOnly: true,
        fgColor: '#009900',
        bgColor: '#00ff00'
    });
});
```

### CSS:

```
.dial {
// options
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: The only way to change a canvas is to redraw it, you can't style it directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792955/change-color-of-canvas-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Plugin seems to put a canvas above your input. 
So what you want to achieve is to change the color of the stuff drawn in that canvas.
Since you can't manipulate the contents of a canvas with css, you aren't able to change the colors without using Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

i manage to change only the numbers in it but still canot change the circle

you just put this line in your .css and it will change the color

.dial { color: #ff3738 !important; }