# How can I get the new value of HTML colorpicker when it changes?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, html5-canvas, onchange

I'm developing a web app that needs to change colour of HTML `canvas` based on the values of `colorpicker`.

I have a `colorpicker` in HTML that I need to get `value` from every time it updates.

```
<input type="color" value="#ff0800" id="color">
```

Currently, this is the code that is associated with the `colorpicker` in my javascript file.

```
var backRGB = document.getElementById("color").value;
```

I am really not sure how this can be achieved.

I have tried other stack exchange question but none of them really meet my requirements so I would really appreciate if someone could show me how this can be achieved.

Comment: are you calling this on onchange event of input tag? if yes whats the error you are getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to update the value of `backRGB` variable when the `colorpicker` value is changed.

To achieve that, you need to attach a handler to the `onchange` event of your `colorpicker`:

```
document.getElementById("color").onchange = function() {
  backRGB = this.value;
}
```

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
var backRGB = document.getElementById("color").value;

document.getElementById("color").onchange = function() {
  backRGB = this.value;
  console.log(backRGB);
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0800" id="color">
```

Comment: ohh I am sorry about that... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" on the line where I declare varRGB

Comment: Ok, didi you gave the `id= "color"` to your colorpicker? Are you running the code after document load?

Comment: i have both the ID's matched so that shouldn't be a problem. if by document load you mean that declaring the backRGB variable that is a global variable in my code..

Comment: No I mean you need to run the code after the page is loaded, can you please make a [**fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your whole code? So you can reproduce the problem?!

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit... it works somewhat ... it updates the colour once or twice and then gives me the same error. I can't message you since I don't have enough reputation but if possible can you message me so I can give you the jsfiddle link (i don't want it to be public since it's a private code....

Comment: @Abby The problem is with the code you are using to register the change event, you need to change the line `backRGB = backRGB.value;` to `backRGB = this.value;`, because this way you are setting an `undefined` value inside `backRGB`.

Comment: yes.. the colour changing works now.. thanks :) but it still has a bug where when I move the mouse over canvas for the first time (after refreshing the page) it changes the colour to black and to red once I hover over a branch... any ideas why this might be caused?

Comment: @Abby Ah that's another problem, I think it's because of the line `ctx.fillStyle = backRGB;` it tries to give an object to the color value in the beginning because `backRGB`isn't yet defined. And that's because of the line `var backRGB = document.getElementById("backColor");` where you are selecting the colorpicker and not its value, change it to `var backRGB = document.getElementById("backColor").value;` and everything will be perfect.

Comment: yep that worked... i will now mark your answer as the correct even though the comments are kinda important

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the answers already given, We can also attach **oninput** event handler instead of **onchange** event. This is another way we can monitor the color picker events from the user.

This event is similar to the **onchange** event. The difference is that the **oninput** event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while **onchange** occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed. The other difference is that the **onchange** event also works on  elements. Here is an example:

```
const backRGB = document.querySelector(".backRCB");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");

color.addEventListener("input",(event)=>{
   backRGB.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
   // You can also do it with the event object as event object holds the value of the current color
   //  backRGB.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
});
```

Hope that  would be helpful to many users.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Akshaykn I am glad I was able to help Mate. God Bless you :)

Answer (score 3):

Solution with pure javascript:

//listen to the "change event" attached to your color input

```
document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("change", onChangeColor);
```

function that get fired after the input value change:

```
function onChangeColor() {

   console.log(this.value); //this.value contains the hexadecimal value of your input
   //change your canvas color

}
```

to change the canvas color check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792955/change-color-of-canvas-element)

Comment: Thank you for the pure javascript solution using addEventListener(). This really helped